# Use AOP in interface method

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I've been reading but I only found very old post, and I was looking forward to know if nowadays it is possible to use AOP pointcut in an interface method

```
@IHandler
public interface SpiHandler extends SpiExtensions {

    @SpiExtension
    Future<Either<ErrorPayload, EntityPayLoad>> getEntity(String condition);

}
```

This is my annotation

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SpiExtension {

}
```

And this is the Aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class ServiceLoaderAspect {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(spiExtension)")
    public Object aroundSourceMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SpiExtension spiExtension) throws Throwable {
        ServiceLoaderAspect.aroundSourceMethod(joinPoint, spiExtension);
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

The version that I'm using is

> org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5

My Spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="serviceLoader" class="com.spi.aspect.ServiceLoaderAspect"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spi.aspect" />


</beans>
```

Comment: I've been fiddling around with AOP earlier this year, in some cases it wouldn't even work if it wasn't on the interface declaration

Comment: But in both or only in the interface?

Comment: only the interface. you can always put in both, but I don't think that changed the behaviour. Have you tried? what do you get as a result?

Comment: Not able to reach the aspect class method. Could you please can provide some code of your solution?

Comment: this can have a number of causes. What AOP framework are you using? How is your configuration? ...

Comment: I update my question. Take a look if you can

Comment: my Around is something like this: @Around(value = "@annotation(" + METHOD_BASED + ".AroundMethod) && atExecution()")
    public void aroundMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint jPoint) throws Throwable {

Comment: and atExecution() is like this: @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution() {

    }

Comment: Sorry I dont understand

Comment: I mean that this: @Around(value = "@annotation(spiExtension)") in your code might be too little

Comment: unfortunately I dont know any possible method, that's why I'm using the annotation as a filter of the pointcut

Comment: Just to clarify If I add the annotation not only in the interface method but in the impementation itself it working and stop in the Around

Comment: personally, I always make sure not to apply aop on methods with parent (either interface, or parent class) methods, just in case this might pop up